# ajax from iframe to my document

Tags: ajax, iframe

im trying to get my iframe ajax script to change the content of a div into the main document wich is not an iframe. just the document.

To send into my iframe i use

```
parent.frames[user].document.getElementById(box).innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
```

user is the iframe name

How do i send stuff back to my document from the iframe??

UPD

I figured out that its not working with IE compatibility. Its working with other browsers with this line

```
parent.document.getElementById(box).innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
```

Notice how there is no frame.

The funy thing is that its woking in all browsers if i catch the event on a div but if i try to catch the event on a form button its not !!

Comment: Are both documents from the same domain?

Comment: ditto, make sure you don't run into security constraints of cross domains.

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.document.getElementById(box).innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
```

This is working in my case